# Cookies, Authentication, Signing up - rails 4 and Ember js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ember.js

So I created a rails app with the ability to sign up, receive a welcome email, sign up - reset the password (again receive an email) and be able to sign in with the option to remember the password. fully tested, both integration and back end tests.

Now I want to bring ember js into this so I added the following gems ...

```
gem 'ember-data-source', '>= 1.0.0.beta.3', '< 2.0'
gem 'emblem-rails', '~> 0.1'

gem 'ember-auth-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'ember-auth-request-jquery-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'ember-auth-response-json-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'ember-auth-strategy-token-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'ember-auth-session-cookie-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'ember-auth-module-ember_data-rails', '~> 1.0'

# for testing, in the testing section:
gem 'jasmine'
```

And then in my routes I went and did:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resource :users
    end
  end
```

And added the appropriate user contoller.

My question for you guys is:

1. I want to add ember to handle ALL the update, delete, create for users.
2. Ember for dealing with sessions and cookies.
3. Ember for allowing you to reset your password and receive welcome emails.

I have two sets of controllers, one for regular html - so your regular controller, and one under api/v1/users_controller.rb

What tutorials or steps are included to do this? I built everything from scratch instead of using devise ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a mouthful of gems. Have you looked at this? http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-1/